# [MySQL innodbcluster]Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating data files

Tags: mysql-innodb-cluster, mysql-operator

I have installed MySQL operator v8.3.0-1.1.2 in the K8s cluster which is running. When I deploy the Mysql Innodbcluster, I get the below error,

Mysql Container

```
2024-02-27T04:34:29.055581Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2024-02-27T04:34:29.055635Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-02-27T04:34:29.471607Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-02-27T04:34:29.471922Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-02-27T04:34:29.471951Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Please help me to solve this issue in the K8s environment!